# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the XXX after upgrade from 8 to 9

Tags: node.js, nestjs

Nestjs app stop working after upgrading from version 8 to 9

I recently upgraded my nestjs project from 8.x.x to 9.2.1
Since this moment my application stop working and I'm keep getting error:  "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the XXX" in all of my resources.
Before I upgraded everything worked perfect.

```
[Nest] 410513  - 08/12/2022, 17:07:21   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the LoanService (PrismaService, ConfigService, StatusesHelper, LoanHelper, QuestionnaireHelper, EventEmitter, DATABASE_CONNECTION, ?). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [7] is available in the LoanModule context.
```

Here is my service DI constractor:

```
import { StatusesHelper } from 'src/helpers/statuses.service';
import { LoanHelper } from 'src/helpers/loan.service';
import { Db, ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
import { QuestionnaireHelper } from 'src/helpers/questionnaire.helper';
import { RunWeights } from 'src/deal/events/run-weights.event';
import { EventEmitter2 } from '@nestjs/event-emitter';
import { User } from '@prisma/client';
import { TwilioClient } from 'nestjs-twilio';


@Injectable()
export class LoanService {
  constructor(
    private prisma: PrismaService
    , private config: ConfigService
    , private statuses: StatusesHelper
    , private readonly loanHelper: LoanHelper
    , private questionnaireHelper: QuestionnaireHelper
    , private readonly eventEmitter: EventEmitter2
    , @Inject('DATABASE_CONNECTION') private db: Db
    , private readonly twilio: TwilioClient
  ) { }
```

Can someone please help me figure it out?
thanks.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: @tadman - You  are totally right, this is my first post :)

Answer (score 0):

It happens most of the time due to either that module is not imported or there is a circular dependency.